# regex error on apache nifi (replace text processor)

Tags: regex, apache-nifi

i'm trying to ingest some data from twitter to elasticsearch using apache nifi, the problem is that all my attributes are written between double quotes, i have an attribute that is supposed to be a number and i don't know how to remove double quotes from it.
i tried using "replace text" process but i get errors.
here is my configuration:

Search Value : `(?s:("([0-9]*[.]){1}[0-9]+"))`
Replacement Value : `${$1:replace('\"', '')}`

Comment: you needs to replace double quotes in attribute value right?

Comment: Try searching for `"([0-9]*[.]?[0-9]+)"` and replace with `$1`. A modified example from the docs: `${att:replaceAll('"([0-9]*[.]?[0-9]+)"', '$1')}`.

Answer (score 2):

sample: `{"a":"1","b": "2"}`

- search value: `(?s)(:\s*)"(\d+)"`
- replacement value: `$1$2`

produces: `{"a":1,"b": 2}`